# Power Automate "Flow widgets" and how we can use & benefit from them

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, jwt, power-automate

I am reading documents about Power Automate from Microsoft Docs and in below link, they are talking about "Flow widgets":

[Integrate Power Automate with websites and apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/embed-flow-dev)

But I am not sure how we can benefit from this? and what does "flow widgets" do exactly? unfortunately the link does not show a picture about how the "flow widgets" looks like, So I am confused. Any advice?

Second question, From my understanding is that "Flow widgets" can be embedded inside public websites, so how users will be using them? For example should the public users login to Power Automate before? and can they use non-Microsoft accounts? as not all public users have Microsoft accounts. In other words what are the differences between "Flow Widgets" and embedding what ever page we want using the standard HTML iframe?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how we can benefit from this? and what does "flow widgets" do exactly?

Flow widgets is used inside Power apps to Ember Power automate within it. In other words we can say that is that it is helpful to trigger other flow from the application. Widget can be helpful to get the list of templates or a built workflow within cloud to have a communication between the host and the widget.

You can check few samples given by [Reza Dorrani](https://rezadorrani.com/index.php/category/flow/) on [PowerApps & Flow](https://rezadorrani.com/index.php/2018/04/30/powerapps-flow/).

> can they use non-Microsoft accounts?

Public users can only give the inputs to the flow but not use it. In order to use flow widgets one must need to have either  a Microsoft Account or work or school account.